# Enable delete when edit button pushed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to enable delete on the UITableView when the EDIT button is pushed on the navbar. Currently I have narrowed it down to:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if(editing == YES)
    {

        // Your code for entering edit mode goes here
    } else {
        // Your code for exiting edit mode goes here
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that the UITableView is in a container view within a UIView which houses the EDIT button, so needs to be targeted and I am also unsure how to show delete for all the UITableView Items at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how to get the Edit button's action method to speak to the table view, there is something wrong with your architecture; it is up to you to set things up so that objects that need to be able to see each other, can do so.

There is nothing else to do. Once you have told the table view to `setEditing:animated:` (with `editing:` set to YES), the delete buttons (minus signs) will automatically appear at the left of all the cells.

But making something happen when the user asks to delete a cell is up to you. (See my full discussion [here](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_deleting_table_items).)

Also note that, by default, the user can *always* swipe left to show the right-side Delete button.